# Trouble setting up Git for Windows: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to set Git up on my Windows machine but having trouble. When I run `ssh -T git@github.com` I get the error message `Permission denied (publickey)`

When I run `ssh -v git@github.com` I get the following log:

```
$ ssh -v git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Kyle/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Kyle/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Kyle/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debia
n-5github2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Kyle/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Kyle/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/Kyle/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Kyle/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to my problem?

Comment: Did you upload your key files to GitHub? (Just checking.)

Comment: hey, yeah keys added to github as well

Comment: I had some initial trouble last year and added a few notes to my fork of GitHub's help files https://github.com/github/help.github.com/pull/48 - It may help.

Answer (score 1):

From [github ssh-issues faq](http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/):

> **Permission denied (publickey)**
>
> This is usually caused when ssh cannot find your keys. Make sure your
>   key is in the default location, ~/.ssh. If you run ssh-keygen again
>   and just press enter at all 3 prompts it will be placed here
>   automatically. Then you can add the contents of id_rsa.pub to your
>   account. If id_rsa.pub doesn’t work try id_dsa.pub. You might need to
>   generate a new dsa key with ssh-keygen -t dsa if you just have an rsa
>   key.

Have you checked this?

Comment: hi yeah both keys are in the correct folder, ive also tried using dsa with no change